# Name of the file decompressed after using tar

Tags: bash, tar

Basically new to bash and what I want to do is to decompress a file and shortly after obtain all of the files inside this new decompressed file to loop through them.

As I am new to bash I am kind of struggline a little bit and the fastest way I found to do it is hardcoding the name of the compressed file.

As I don't want to hardcode more variables I was wondering if I can save the variable of the decompressed file (it's the same without .tar.gz) after running the command to decompress.

```
COMP_FILE=$(ls data_compressed*)
tar zxf ${COMP_FILE}
FILE_LIST=$(ls $COMP_FILE)
echo $FILE_LIST
```

Pretty new to BASH so feel free to correct or point to any directions where I can learn more.

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose you are new to bash? :-)

Comment: @linuxfan Yeah it's the first thing I said lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%` operator can be used to remove the suffix, see `man bash`: `"${COMP_FILE%.tar.gz}"`

All this below can break when there are  (space char) or other special chars in the filenames, in the tarball.

Give a try to this:

```
COMP_FILE=$(ls data_compressed*)
tar zxf "${COMP_FILE}"
FILE_LIST=$(ls "${COMP_FILE%.tar.gz}")
cd "${COMP_FILE%.tar.gz}"
for filename in ${FILE_LIST} ; do
  printf "Filename is %s\n" "${filename}"
done
```

Thanks to `v`, you could imagine loop over the filenames while `tar` is extracting the data:

```
for filename in $(tar xzvf data_compressed*) ; do
  printf "Filename is %s\n" "${filename}"
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much this does what I wanted